# NestList and Euler's method

Tags: differential-equations, programming, numerical-integration

I am new to mathematica and so just experimenting with various programming constructs. Recently have been looking at `NestList` and how I could use this to implement [Euler's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).

```
Euler[a0_, b0_, steps0_, init0_] := 
 Module[{a = a0, b = b0, steps = steps0, init = init0, t, y},
  dt = (b - a)/steps;
  f[{t0_, y0_}] := y0 Sin[t0];
  euler[{t_, y_}] := {t + dt, y + dt f[{t, y}]};
  NestList[euler, {a, init}, steps]
  ]
approx = ListPlot[Euler[0, 2 \[Pi], 30, 1]]
```

I came up with this implementation but when I set the number of steps to > 20 the performance is very poor and the function never returns. I've tried it for a number of different functions and the results agrees with `DSolve`. Is it better to use For, Do, etc.?

---

I thought i would experiment a little more with NestList & Euler so i implemented a small example that shows how to solve a 2nd order ODE for a damped system. As noted above in this example if i set c,k,m to be an integer value vs a decimal then mathematica evaluates them differently giving very different performance characteristics.

```
Euler[a0_,b0_,steps0_,x0_,v0_]:=Module[{a=a0,b=b0,
steps=steps0,xinit=x0,vinit=v0},
dt= (b-a)/steps;
k=5.0;
m=2.0;
c=0.5;
f[{t_,x_,v_}]:=v;
g[{t_,x_,v_}]:= -x (k/m) -c v; 
euler[{t_,x_,v_}]:={t+dt,
x+dt f[{t,x,v}],
v+dt g[{t,x,v}]};
NestList[euler,{a,xinit,vinit},steps]
]
result =Euler[0,20,100000,1,1];
ListPlot [ {result[[All,2]],result[[All,3]]},PlotRange->All]
```

[image: Damped Oscillations]

Comment: If you wrap your definition of `f[{t0_, y0_}] := y0 Sin[t0];` around a `N` it should improve speed: `f[{t0_, y0_}] := N[y0 Sin[t0]];`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and it seems to work but why do i need the N[] ? I understand what N[] does just not sure why its needed in this case ?

Comment: The way you had it, `Euler[a0, b0, n, init]` was treating the expression symbolically. Try doing `NestList[Sqrt[1 + #] &, 1, 10]` as opposed to `NestList[N@Sqrt[1 + #] &, 1, 10]` to understand the difference.

Comment: And NO, it isn't better to use For[]/Do[] at all. You're in the right path

Comment: Thanks for the info, much appreciated. NestList is actually a very neat solution to this problem.

Comment: David, I see that you have [voted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) only a single time, and that you have not [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/158428) any answers.  Please consider participating in these ways.

Answer (score 6):

The good thing with *Mathematica* is that when you supply exact numbers to your computation, it will never make any evaluation which looses information (find more about this in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10965/187)). If you want to see this in action, you could look at the expressions building up inside your `f` call during the computation. You can wrap `Trace` around your `Euler` call to see this

```
Trace[Euler[0, 2 Pi , 7, 1], f[__]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Consider that this is only for 7 steps! If you are using 20+ steps, the expression will fill books which makes it kind of hard for *Mathematica* to handle them fast.

Let's make one little adjustment and give *one* argument as non-exact number. This tells *Mathematica* that it can calculate all expression with finite precision

```
Trace[Euler[0,2.Pi ,7,1],f[__]]
(*
{{{{{{{f[{0,1}]}}}},{{{{f[{0.897598,1.}]}}}},
{{{{f[{1.7952,1.70177}]}}}},{{{{f[{2.69279,3.19098}]}}}},
{{{{f[{3.59039,4.43371}]}}}},{{{{f[{4.48799,2.70699}]}}}},
{{{{f[{5.38559,0.338121}]}}}}}}}
*)
```

It's hard to see, but I inserted a `.` after the 2 ;-).

Now you can check yourself

```
ListPlot[Euler[0, 2. \[Pi], 30, 1]] // Timing
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response. I now see exactly what was going on.