# Mathematica Improved Euler's Method

Tags: differential-equations, programming

Population growth in *Mathematica* with `NDSolve`:

```
f[r_, a_, T_] := NDSolve[{x' t] == r*x[t]*(1 - x[t]), x[0] == a}, x, {t, 0, T}]

s1 = f[0.1, 0.5, 30];
s2 = f[0.1, 2, 30];

Plot[{x[t] /. s1, x[t] /. s2, 1}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[t] /. f[0.3, 0.2 n, 10], {n, 1, 10}]], PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

How can we solve it with Improved Euler's method?

```
P[q_, h_, N_] := (
  u[0] = 1; 
  Do[u[n + 1] = u[n] + h*f[n*h + (h*q/2), u[n] + (h*q/2)*f[n*h, u[n]]], {n, 0, N}]
 )

f[x_, t_] := r*x[t]*(1 - x[t])
```

Comment: It looks like you've already written down some code that's supposed to implement the "improved Euler's method". What exactly is your question? If it's not working, can you explain how? Please provide more details.

Comment: note that your second `Plot` expression is missing a plotting variable and range specification.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22555/27951) for an implementation of Euler's method; the same answer also contains a link to a document that discusses a similar implementation of the Improved Euler Method ("Método Euler Mejorado") in the file. Although the file is in Spanish, the code is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: ...edit is wrong

Comment: Not good idea to `N` for argument name as it is used by Mathematica

Comment: @Jonathan If I misunderstood your question in my edit, I apologize. Of course you can always revert my edit, or further change it. Use the "edit" link at the bottom left corner of the question.

Comment: Thank yοu for having helped me. It is not about you, I was wrong edit my document:)

Answer (score 7):

generate Improved Euler steps:

```
makeTableRk2Sub[h_, from_, to_, y0_] := 
 Module[{nSteps = Round[(to - from)/h], data, t, y, k1, k2, predictor,
    tbl},
  Array[y, nSteps, 0];
  Array[t, nSteps, 0];
  y[0] = y0; t[0] = from;

  Do[(*Improved Euler loop*)
   k1 = f[t[n], y[n]];
   predictor = y[n] + h k1;
   t[n + 1] = t[n] + h;
   k2 = f[t[n + 1], predictor];
   y[n + 1] = y[n] + h (1/2*(k1 + k2)),
   {n, 0, nSteps}
   ];
  tbl = Table[{t[n], y[n]}, {n, 0, nSteps}]
  ]
```

To use (red is `NDSolve` and blue is improved Euler with large step size)

```
f[t_, y_] := t^2 + y^2; 
h = 0.3; from = 0; to = 5*h; y0 = 0;
tbl = makeTableRk2Sub[h, from, to, y0];
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == t^2 + y[t]^2, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, from, to}];
p1 = ListLinePlot[tbl, Mesh -> All];
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol], {t, from, to}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, {"t", 
      "Comparing Improved Euler to NDSolve"}}, GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 14];

Show[Legended[p2, Style["NDsolve", Red]],Legended[p1, Style["Improved Euler", Blue]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can also remove the typo `Imporoved` in the image too.