# Use Euler method to solve differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

1. Use *Euler's Method* or the *Modified Euler's* to solve the differential equation 
   ${dy/dt=y^2+t^2-1, y(-2)=-2}$ on $[- 2, 2]$.  Take `h = 0.2`  (`n = 20` iterations).
2. See if *Mathematica* will give an analytic solution to this problem.

   If it does compare the analytic solution found in Problems 1 and 2.

   If *Mathematica* will not give an analytic solution, compare your solutions to the numerical solution on $[-2, 2]$ given by *Mathematica*.

For the first problem, I am confused of the interval is not $[0,2]$ but $[-2,2]$
I have no idea with these two problems, can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello ! Welcome ! I am sorry, but you clearly did not research the problems in question. Nevertheless I will not give you a tip on the first one, but on the second - look up `DSolve` in the documentation centre.

Comment: Thank you, I will look up NDSolve and DSolve

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11924)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

I edited to replace `h` with `N@h` as suggested by MichaelE2, to prevent `Mathematica` slowdown if exact `h` is provided by the user.

**Note for future users**: I initially had a procedural approach posted, if you're interested in that method see the edit history.
I present a Functional approach, this is *Mathematica* after all.

```
SetAttributes[eulerMethod, HoldAll];

eulerMethod[func_, {x_, x0_, xmax_}, {y_, y0_}, h_] := 
 Module[{EulerStep, hh = N@h},  
  EulerStep[{xi_, yi_}] := Module[{xold = xi, yold = yi, xnew, ynew}, 
    xnew = xold + hh; 
    ynew = yold + hh ReleaseHold[Hold[func] /. {HoldPattern[x] -> xold, 
          HoldPattern[y] -> yold}]; {xnew, ynew}];
      NestList[EulerStep, {x0, y0}, Round[(xmax - x0)/hh]
     ]
  ]
```

**Usage**

```
sol = eulerMethod[y^2 + t^2 - 1, {t, -2, 2}, {y, -2}, 0.2];
```

You can compare it to the built in `NDSolve` by plotting both in the range `[-2, 2]`

```
ListLinePlot[sol, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `NDSolve`:

```
nd = NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 + t^2 - 1, y[-2] == -2}, y[t], {t, -2, 2}];
```

Then

```
Plot[y[t] /. nd, {t, -2, 2}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, our `eulerMethod` needs more iteration (smaller step size) to get close to the more accurate `NDSolve`

If we increase the number of iterations (decrease h) we nail the accuracy

```
sol2 = eulerMethod[y^2 + t^2 - 1, {t, -2, 2}, {y, -2}, 0.01]

ListLinePlot[sol2, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Darker@Green]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, this looks very much like the result from `NDSolve`

You can get an exact solution using `DSolve` as follows:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 + t^2 - 1, y[-2] == -2}, y[t], t]
```

Comment: @vicky1229, RunnyKine, You might want to consider apply `N` somewhere in case someone does `eulerMethod[y^2 + t^2 - 1, {t, -2, 2}, {y, -2}, 1/100]`.  See also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22042/nestlist-and-eulers-method/22048#22048. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I just saw your comment I haven't been active in a while. I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing that out and for the upvote.